# Complex sort of a multidimensional array by key and a child value

Tags: php, arrays

I am in need of some help doing a complex sort of a multidimensional array.

It is structured as follows:

```
Array (
  [04/10/2017] => Array ( 
    [438] => Array ( 
      [start_time] => 19:30
      [end_time] => 20:00
      [booking_name] => Test
    )
  )
)
```

Date followed by ID followed by values, one of which is the start time.

I wish to sort the array firstly by the date key and then secondly by the 'start_time' value. I can sort by date easily enough using ksort, but I can't figure out how to secondary sort by the time. I have tried looping and using array_multisort but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: after using `ksort` use `uasort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: @B.Desai Doing two separate sort operations won't do much good here.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by a key *and* a contained value, use `uksort`:

```
uksort($array, function ($keyA, $keyB) use ($array) {
    $valueA = $array[$keyA][...];
    $valueB = $array[$keyB][...];

    if ($keyA == $keyB) {
        return $valueA <=> $valueB;
    } else {
        return $keyA <=> $keyB;
    }
});
```

I'm leaving the specific comparisons open here (just using the generic `<=>` here), you'll need to fill in those blanks yourself. But this illustrates the general logic to sort by keys first and nested values second.